# Problems with LINQ WhereClause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, where-clause, edmx

Many thanks to leppie: 
Currently I got

```
Expression<Func<vwMailMerge,bool>> whereClause= null;
List<vwMailMerge> mailMergeItems = null;

int personType = mailMergeSettings.PersonType.ToInteger();
if (personType > 0)
{
    whereClause = this.MailMergeWhereClause(whereClause, f => f.MemberTypeId == personType);
}
if (mailMergeSettings.PersonIds != null)
{
    var personIds = mailMergeSettings.PersonIds.ToGuidArray();
    if (personIds != null && personIds.Length > 0)
    {
        var personList = personIds.ToList();
        whereClause = this.MailMergeWhereClause(whereClause, f => personList.Contains(f.UserId));
    }
}

mailMergeItems = this.ObjectContext.vwMailMerges.Where(whereClause).ToList();
private Expression<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>> MailMergeWhereClause(params Expression<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>>[] wheres)
{
    if (wheres.Length == 0)
    {
        return x => true;
    }
    Expression result;   
    if (wheres[0] == null)
    {
        result = wheres[1].Body;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>>(result, wheres[1].Parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        result = wheres[0].Body;
        for (int i = 1; i < wheres.Length; i++)
        {
            result = Expression.And(result, wheres[i].Body);
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>>(result, wheres[0].Parameters);
        }     
    }
}
```

When it gets to "mailMergeItems =" it drops and gives error: "The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression."

I've noticed that when checking only for people, or only for membertypeId, it works properly.. but combined the 2nd gives a error on it's "f=>" I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reformat your question better with the code tool.

However it looks like you could approach the problem in this way to avoid all those func expressions floating around:

```
this.ObjectContext.vwMailMerges.Where(mm=>IsValidMailMerge(mm,personType)).ToList()


private bool IsValidMailMerge(YourType mailmerge, YourType2 personType)
{
if(...) // type specific criteria here
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot more "where's" that will be added to the whereclause so I think this is a good way.

Comment: Fair enough, if it is an expression based system you are creating then go with leppie's idea. Essentially an Expression is the c# lambda code for a condition and a Func is the expression built into a clr method. Expressions can be passed around easily but must be built at runtime to be used. You can read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: In the end.. we threw out the WhereClause.
Mostly because we found out that we had the revamp the entire section due to changes in the plan.
Now we are using this as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `Func`, you need to use `Expression<Func>`.

The `+` can be done via `Expression.And`.

Update (not tested):

```
Expression<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>> whereClause = null;
...
Expression<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>> MailMergeWhereClause(
   params Expression<Func<vwMailMerge, bool>>[] wheres)
{
  if (wheres.Length == 0) return x => true;
  Expression result = wheres[0].Body;
  for (int i = 1; i < wheres.Length; i++)
  {
    //probaby needs a parameter fixup, exercise for reader
    result = Expression.And(result, wheres[i].Body); 
  }
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<vwMailMerge,bool>>(result, wheres[0].Parameters);
}
```

Update 2:

The above approach fails as I expected. It might be easy to solve on .NET 4 using the `ExpressionVistor` class. For .NET 3.5 (or if aforementioned is too hard) the following should work.

The approach is the append the where clauses in the `IQueryable` directly so you end up with:

```
somequery.Where(x => x.foo).Where(x => x.bar).Where(x => x.baz)
```

IOW, you can just add them as required, but it will require some changes to the logic/flow of the code you pasted.

Comment: @Theun: I said I was fixing it, now fixed, but is probably still incomplete, see the comment.

Comment: I thank you for your aid, sadly I didn't get it fixed so I stepped back to using normal linq.